# Can "startup" function in UART driver know which tty device(ex. "ttyUSB0") was opened in Linux?

Tags: linux-device-driver, uart, tty

Can "startup" function in my UART driver know which tty device(ex. "/dev/ttyUSB0") was opened in Linux? 
I really need to know the tty device name because the UART driver deliver data according to the tty devices. Note that the tty devices could bind to the same UART driver.

Ex) $mknod -m 666 /dev/ttyUSB2 c 246 1
    $mknod -m 666 /dev/ttyUSB3 c 246 1
    (both ttyUSB2 and USB3 bind to the same UART driver which is 246 1)

Thank you.
//Daum

Comment: Yes, because of the relationship of major & minor numbers to device nodes.  But a UART driver would not be servicing a device named **/dev/ttyUSB0**.

Comment: @sawdust and what by your opinion is servicing that kind of nodes?

Comment: @0andriy -- For recent kernels, conventional UART/USART drivers for serial terminals are at **drivers/tty/serial/**, whereas USB serial devices are at **drivers/usb/serial/**.

Comment: I really need to know the tty device name because the UART driver deliver data according to the tty devices. Note that the tty devices could bind to the same UART driver. Ex) $mknod -m 666 /dev/ttyUSB2 c 246 1     Ex) $mknod -m 666 /dev/ttyUSB3 c 246 1

Comment: @sawdust, so, you are telling that USB serial is not UART driver? What is it then?

Comment: I meant, USB serial is a UART driver. I would like to open the same port using different tty name so as to listen the receiving data by two processes.

Comment: Your example misuses the minor number.  Study https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124225/are-the-major-minor-number-unique/124233#124233  You're asking an XY question.

Comment: @0andriy -- If you're a user and/or only concerned with the exposed interface, then you can conflate these two types of devices. But a kernel developer, especially one writing device drivers, would consider the *internal* interface of the device more salient.  Linux UART/USART (aka serial) drivers must support a low-level serial API that includes the `struct uart_ops`.  Whereas USB serial drivers are simpler, do not support the low-level serial API, and have instead  a `struct usb_serial_driver`.  Study the kernel documentation.

Comment: @sawdust, you missed one important detail, i.e. what is the hardware is there. Good kernel developer should understand what it is and how it’s bound to the platform. In this case it’s an UART hardware on one side and USB bus for transport data on another. Thus, the UART driver heavily relies on the transport implementation, and split in the source is done by transport, then by actual hardware block. Nonetheless the UART doesn’t stop being UART because of split in software. Read the data sheet.

Comment: @0andriy *"you missed one important detail"* -- No, you fail to comprehend the reference to the "exposed interface".